# Can't open terminal through tightvncserver on Ubuntu 20 / no gnome panel

Tags: 20.04, vnc

I followed https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-20-04 by putting

```
xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
startxfce4 &
```

into my `.vnc/startup` and I can sucessfully log into the VNC and use nautilus and other apps but there's no maximize/close buttons and most importantly I cannot open terminal. I click on it on the dock and nothing happens

I also tried putting this:

```
gnome-panel &
gnome-settings-daemon &
metacity &
gnome-terminal &
nautilus &
```

and I could sucessfully log and see nautilus open but using it to open terminal results in nothing, and I also see no other thing other than nautilus (no icones to click)

I'd preferably use gnome on VNC but I can't make both work

Comment: In your .vnc/startup, you are starting XFCE desktop environment and not GNOME, so it's possible that applications that are highly dependent on GNOME, like the ones you listed, will not work correctly. You should try to start GNOME session instead of XFCE in your .vnc/startup file, however I'm not sure which command exactly you should use to run this, maybe gnome-session ?

Comment: @raj when I tried with xfce I disabled gnome. I tried gnome now and added `gnome-session &` along with the other ones `gnome-panel &
gnome-settings-daemon &
metacity &
gnome-terminal &
nautilus &` and it had the same behaviour

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For xfce, the default action of open terminal is to open x-terminal-emulator, which in turn links to gnome-terminal.wrapper. You can get this info from Applications->File Manager->Edit->Configure custom actions..., and Applications->Settings->Settings Manager->Preferred Applications->Utilities, also to trace the symlink of x-terminal-emulator.

The thing is that gnome-terminal is trying to connect to D-Bus but failed to get a response and timed out, to verify it you could launch D-Bus first, e.g. `$ dbus-launch gnome-terminal` and you will see a gnome terminal pops up.

The easiest way to solve this is to use an alternative terminal. To do it, open a xfce terminal from Applications->System->Xfce Terminal, use command `$ sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator`, choose an alternative from the list instead of the default gnome-terminal, like xfce4-terminal or xterm, then you should be good to go to open a terminal.

For using gnome instead of xfce, try put the following to your xstartup file, start the vncserver and check the log file, fix any errors by installing the missing packages, then you should be able to see the gnome DE from vnc client.

```
xrdb $HOME/.Xresources 
xsetroot -solid grey

export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1 
export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP="GNOME-Flashback:Unity" 
export XDG_MENU_PREFIX="gnome-flashback-"

unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS

gnome-session --session=gnome-flashback-metacity --disable-acceleration-check &
```

Comment: This worked for me also on Ubuntu 18.04. Thank you!